# I can't catch exceptions in an Invoked delegate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-debugging

I have a delegate which is attached to an event in the Excel interop component. The goal is to update a winforms control with updated info from Excel. Since I'm changing Control properties I need to use Invoke:

```
public delegate void DataGridViewUpdate(object[,] data);

...

excel.InteractiveEdit( delegate(object[,] data) { 
    Invoke(new Common.DataGridViewUpdate(back_from_excel), new object[] { data }); 
});

...

private void back_from_excel(object[,] data) {
    // datagridview updating code
    // an exception is thrown here !
}
```

(This code is in the Form class that I'm updating so it's Invoking on `this`)

Basically my problem is that when an exception occurs in the `back_from_excel(object[,] data)` method, the debugger doesn't catch it. I know the delegate is running in the correct UI thread because I have no problems manipulating form controls.

Specifically what happens is that when `back_from_excel` hits an unhandled exception, it stops executing at that point. The rest of the application continues running and is responsive. The debugger **doesn't pause**. The output pane shows:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in My Application.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

It doesn't give me any hints about which line caused the problem, just that it's somewhere in the .exe.

My question is: am I doing the `Invoke` thing right? It seems kind of strange to have delegate - Invoke - delegate chained together like that, but I do need to pass a delegate that Invokes a delegate. Is my problem in Visual Studio rather than in C#? If so how do I get the debugger re-attached to that UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "first chance exception" indicates that an exception was thrown, but that it was caught at some point. Since you're passing a delegate to the InteractiveEdit method, that method can easily swallow any exceptions produced by the delegate.

By default, Visual Studio will only catch exceptions that don't get caught. If you want to catch all exceptions, regardless of whether they are caught, you need to configure Visual Studio to break on all exceptions. See [this link](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks; the setting to catch all exceptions in the debugger was enough for my needs. I still don't understand where the exceptions were going though; they certainly weren't being caught by my code, and they were errors (like null reference exceptions) which would typically be programmer-handled.

Comment: @Brian: I'm guessing that the `excel.InteractiveEdit` method is part of the Excel Interop library, right? It probably swallows exceptions that are produced by the delegate you send it in order to maintain its internal integrity.

Comment: No, actually InteractiveEdit is my own method. It adds the delegate to an event which is triggered by the Excel Interop though. You're probably right though; that makes me feel better about this weirdness.